# jQuery hide/show some part of the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which I am giving a part of it in the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="yes" value="1" />Yes

<div id="divyes">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="hey">Hey</label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" id="hey" name="hey">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="yes2" name="yes2" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="yes3" name="yes3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to show or hide some part of the form according to checkbox's checked statu.

```
$(function () {
    $("#divyes").hide();

    $("#yes").click(function () {

        if ($("#yes").attr("checked")) {
            $("#divyes").slideDown();
        } else {
            $("#divyes").slideUp();
            $("#divyes > input").text("");
        }
    });
});
```

You can see the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/a3j5V/3/)

If I select `jQuery 1.8.3` from the left panel it works fine but if I select `1.10.1` it does not work. I am also using `1.10.2` on my project. So I want to know how I can do my work without using `.slideDown()`/`.show()` and `.slideUp()`/`.show()`? In other words, is my logic good or can you offer better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.change()` event and an instance of `this`

```
$("#yes").change(function () {

    if (this.checked) {
        $("#divyes").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#divyes").slideUp();
        $("#divyes > input").text("");
    }
});
```

The fail is happening on the `.attr` method - it should be `.prop` to check, however you can just do `this.checked` for an even faster result.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a3j5V/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  var yes_cont = $("#divyes");
  var yes_checkbox = $("#yes");
  yes_cont.hide();
  yes_checkbox.click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        yes_cont.slideToggle('up');
    }  else {
        yes_cont.slideToggle('down');
      }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rY4Ts/15/

Answer (score 0):

i made it with `toggle`

```
$('#divyes').toggle('slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a3j5V/11/